# Sort an array in 4 groups with SORT_BY

Tags: ruby

I have a 2D array and I need to sort by values in those arrays using sort_by! (e.g when second value of the array is nil it belongs to the first group)

I done this with each method, but I need a prettier/readable code.

What I have so far:
arry pattern: [[164, nil, 6], [163, nil, 6], [162, nil, 6], [161, nil, 7], [160, "FSDL", 6]]

```rb
        matches.each do |match|
          first_group << match.first if match.second.blank? && match.last == 6
          second_group << match.first if match.second.present? && match.last == 6
          third_group << match.first if  match.last == 4
          forth_group << match.first if  match.last == 7
        end

return first_group + second_group + third_group + forth_group
```

I wanted to do something like this:

matches.sort_by! { |match| (match.second == nil && match.last == 6)(second_condition) (third_condition) (fourth_condition) }

Comment: What is your expected output for your example pattern ?

Answer (score 0):

I used nil? instead of blank? if you want you can use blank? and present? as per your requirement. sorting can be done as follows

```
matches.sort_by do |match|
    if(match[1].nil? && match.last == 6)
        "1 #{match.first}"
    elsif(not match[1].nil? && match.last == 6)
        "2 #{match.first}"
    elsif(match.last == 4)
        "3 #{match.first}"
    elsif(match.last == 7)
        "4 #{match.first}"
    else
        "5 #{match.first}"
    end
end
```

With above code if anything not matching the conditions will be appended to last

It will produce following output for given sample

```
[[162, nil, 6], [163, nil, 6], [164, nil, 6], [160, "FSDL", 6], [161, nil, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not completely clear the expected output, but if this returns it, I'm going to add an explanation.

```
matches = [[164, nil, 6], [163, nil, 6], [162, nil, 6], [161, nil, 7], [160, "FSDL", 6] ]

matches.group_by(&:last).tap { |h| h[6] = h[6].group_by { |e| e[1].nil? } }
         .tap { |h| h.default = [] }
         .then { |h| h[6][true] + h[6][false] + h[4] + h[7] }
         .map(&:first)

#=> [164, 163, 162, 160, 161]
```

Comment: In case you want so sort also nested groups (`162, 163, 164`), use `.then { |h| [h[6][true], h[6][false], h[4].sort, h[7].sort] }` and add `.flat_map(&:sort)` just before the last `map(&:first)`.

Comment: I need the following order:

1st -> (`arry.second == nil && arry.last == 6`)
2nd -> (`arry.second == not nil && arry.last == 6`)
3rd ->( `arry.last == 4`)
4th -> (`arry.last == 7`)

Input example :

[[164, nil, 4], [163, nil, 4], [162, nil, 6], [161, nil, 7], [160, "FSDL", 6], [404, "text", 6], [123, "text", 6]]

Expected output:

[[162, nil, 6], [160, "FSDL", 6], [123, "text", 6], [404, "text", 6], [164, nil 4], [163, nil, 4],  [161, nil, 7]]

Comment: I'm not at work right now, but went I get there i'll try your example, but the output in your example is what I expect